# Regular Expressions in F#

Tags: regex, f#

I want to write a regular expression in F# that represents strings which **start & end with "** and can have any sequence of Unicode characters not including double quote or newline.

For example:

> "I want to go home"
>
> "My name is cookya "
>
> ""

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a regular expression like the following :

```
let regex = "^\".*\"$"
```

Comment: Why ? should match even a empty line ?

Comment: yeah, cookya wrote it in question

Answer (score 0):

**Ty this**

```
"[^"]*?"
```

*It could work, but parsing and validating this kind of string you might need a `stack`.*

Comment: Shouldn't I use \" instead of " so that the compiler would ignore the char " and refer to it as part of the string?

Comment: He gave you the pure RegEx, it is your job to escape it correctly.